# Implement CRUD operations with big JSON file in .NET

Tags: c#, json

I have big (about 1 GB) JSON files and I want to implement CRUD operations in  the most efficient way. Deserializing json to a list of appropriate objects for implementing CRUD operations - like 
`List<object> listObjects= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<object>>(json)` - then serializing is very slow.

Is there way to do this or any api?

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea, hopefully you have some flexibility. Can you break up the JSON into their own individual documents? Then you can use a database like Couchbase to index, update en masse, get/set individual fields, etc.

Comment: Not really.  JSON is not a database format.  Imagine you want to change the first string in the file by making it one character longer.  To do so would require 1GB of reads, and 0.999 GB of writes.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  JSON is not a database format.  Imagine you want to change the first string in the file by making it one character longer.  To do so would require 1GB of reads, and 0.999 GB of writes.

Consider loading the file to a database for manipulation.  There are a thousand and one with native JSON support.

If the root of the JSON file is an array, and the array is order insensitive, an efficient API could be built atop JSON + a separate index but I am not aware of one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, just I should use this JSON as a data storage. Yes I can easily implement CRUD operation having this data in data base, but my requirements is to use JSON file  for writing api. Then I should use this api to show data  on a  client. What  about slicing  this big file to small files?

Comment: Slicing a big file to many small files would solve the CRUD problem, but still complicates indexing (you only get one by default - the filename).  Most filesystems have high overhead when working with many thousands of small files unless specifically prepared (block size).  If each record is more than 16KB, the waste will be small (<25%), but if you have many thousands of 256 byte files, you will find that they take up much more space on disk.  Backup/restore, antivirus, and other operations become complicated above a few hundred thousand files on disk.

Comment: If you find an in-place ZIP API, that may be a better bet.  Use the ZIP container as your virtual filesystem, and compact it occasionally.  Same option would be available for TAR, CAB, or even the [COM Compound File API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd3k45e.aspx) (if you want to mix the most accessible data format with the least ).